# Bat File: search .txt with variable

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have a script to deploy to computers. Before that, I need to check a directory with multiple .txt files call "hostname".txt.

Is there a possibility to insert a variable "hostname" to know if the "hostname".txt already exist?

````bat
set host=hostname
If Not Exist "\\share\%host%.txt" (powershell.exe "\\share\script.ps1") else ```
````

Hope you understand my issue.
Thank you

Comment: `%computername%` is the system variable.

Comment: Can you clarify your question more? If I am understanding correctly, you want to see if a file exists with a variable?

Comment: Yes. For example: my txt filename is pcxxx.txt. When hosts call the script, i would like to find if pcxxx.txt exsists with %computername%.txt (thank you Squashman!)

Comment: Got it!!  Thank you Squashman! `set host=%computername%
If Not Exist "\\share\%host%.txt" (powershell.exe "\\share\script.ps1") else (exit)`